# Are there any downsides to including the jquery library on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using javascript for some while now and recently began using jquery which I will admit I am fan of.
`<script type='text/javascript' src='../locationOfJquery/jquery.js'></script>`  allows use of the library in the script tags on that page.  What I want to know is if just including the script tags slows down page load time any, even if there is no jquery code on the page, and also if there are any other major downsides to using jquery

Comment: The minified jQuery source is 32kb.  I wouldn't include unless you are actually using it. jQuery is awesome, there are no downsides!

Comment: If it was 1999, I would say yes.  But in this day and age, where most people have better than dial-up, no... it will not affect performance if you simply include other JS files.

Comment: There are downsides to jQuery...having been a member of SO for a while, I've seen some pretty dreadful uses of jQuery simply because it makes things very easy. It's easy to make unnecessarily inefficient scripts, especially if you learn jQuery before javascript, which many newbies are doing.

Comment: Also, if you're concerned about download speeds, have you seen http://zeptojs.com/? It is a lightweight version of jQuery, using similar syntax. Its good for mobile projects (due to the lack of support for IE)

Comment: I agree it can be used in a more flashy somewhat unecessary way then javascript, but iv been working with js for way longer, just interested in trying out some libraries to see if their capabilities could prove to be of use.

Comment: @kevin628 : I'd agree, if we're only talking about the desktop.   Mobile browsing is definitely akin to 1999.  If you're at all concerned about mobile users browsing the page, you'd be wise to try loading it on say a cell phone with a 480x320 display and an EDGE connection.

Comment: @Chimoo the lightweighted-ness would be nice but the majority if not all of my users use ie...unfotunatly

Comment: @Rocket where does 32kb come from? Is that gzipped as well, because the minified source on its own seems to be 92kb?

Comment: The production version (minified and Gzipped) is around 32k so they say on the jquery website, v1.7.2 at least

Comment: jQuery is estimated to be used by 50% of every website on the whole internet (or at least the ones in their survey which looks like a million or so): http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all I think it's safe to not worry about the impact of the script being downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Put the script tags at the bottom of the page. This will not slow down processing of the DOM before onload events fire.
- Use the minified version of jQuery, which is about as small as a small image/icon.
- If visitors visit more than one page in your site, it will also usually be cached after their first visit. It may also already be pre-cached (or served from a more-local server) if you use a content delivery network (e.g. Google's). Good first impressions are critical.

To further answer smaller questions you had:

- If there is no jQuery code on the page, jQuery must still be parsed. You can see how long it takes your computer to parse jQuery by using a profiling tool such as Chrome's.
- There are frameworks which optimize your javascript on a per-page basis, but those have to trade off the ability to cache a script versus the gains in faster parsing. You almost certainly shouldn't worry about them. jQuery is very lightweight compared to other frameworks.

---

**Numbers:**

For example on Chrome when loading the Stackoverflow website, requesting the jQuery library from the Google CDN, the results were:

- 0.027ms aggregate time spent download jQuery (perhaps cached)
- 35.992ms aggregate time spent evaluating jQuery and performing any default DOM/CSS operations

This is all relative of course. I bet when you loaded this page you did not notice any lag because the entire page took about 630ms to load.

Comment: Ok then yeah there should be no worries in implementing it

Answer (score 2):

The client will have to download the jQuery script (which is quite small). To further optimize you can just use hosted "[Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)" versions from [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=pt-BR#jquery) or [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx). Also remember to use the minified version which downloads faster.

[This article](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) states the reasons why.

Comment: Using CDN isn't going to change things much. That's mostly better for the world and your server than it is for an individual user. It may save them from one download, but after the first time someone hits your page, they won't have to re-download jQuery whether it's linked to a CDN or your server. I'm not saying it isn't a good thing, but it won't change the overall profile of a site using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it is a negligible optimization, but still, It may save that single download for most users (if you have millions of new users that means 30Kb vs million of users bandwidth consumption), plus decrease latency for the few other users that need to download it. All in all it is a win win situation. I think it is worth to jump on the bandwagon.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include it if you are not using it.

32k is a small price to pay, but better to have no request and 0k extra to download.

Also, and more importantly, you may run into conflicts with other frameworks if you are using any.

Comment: Im currently not, at this point im mainly concerned about just optimizing load time one of my bigger webpages, but the functionality of jQuery is definetly a convinience.

Comment: It won't have any substantive impact on load time since the browser will cache it, and the time to run it is miniscule. I agree it's better not to include it on pages it's not used, but not better enough to worry about unless it's really easy (e.g. your framework already has a concept of conditional includes). Not worth losing sleep over. If you have a slow-loading page, it's not jQuery's fault.

Comment: If you're considering using jQuery, then I wouldn't worry about including it now.  The optimization you make by excluding it is tiny.